# Relative cell reference in Excel using different axis

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to make a relative cell reference that extends downwards when I copy the value to the right? Consider this example:

```
10%    100  150  200  250  300
15% 
20%
25%
30%
```

I would like to multiply the horizontal values with the vertical ones, like `100*10%`, `150*15%`, `200*20%` and so on. Can it be done or would I be better off rearranging my data so they both are vertical?

Comment: Are the `100   150   200 ...` on the sheet already? Or is that where you want `=100*10%   =150*15% ...` to go? Where do you want the output?

Comment: Yes, all the numbers in the example are on the sheet already. The position of the output doesn't matter too much, but right below the `100 150 200...` row would probably be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no tidy way of doing this, but you can use the `OFFSET` function to achieve this.

Try this:

```
=B$1*OFFSET($A$1,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$1),0)
```

`COLUMN()` returns the column number of the current cell (`B2` in my example) and `COLUMN($B$1)` returns the column number of the cell that holds `100`. This is written so that the row offset increases by one as the formula is filled to the right. If you're going to put the output somewhere other than in line with the `100   150  200 ...` row, you'll need to tinker with this to get it right.

Comment: Agreed, not very elegant, but does exactly what I needed. Thanks!